# Почему Android выдаёт ошибку после установки приложения?

Tags: android

Подскажите, установил приложение на ОС Android 6, но при попытке запуска выдало  ошибку

```
10163 nor current process has android.permission READ_PHONE_STATE
```

на android 4 таких проблем не возникает как это можно исправить ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Начиная с Android 6 изменились принципы получения разрешений для приложений.
Читайте [официальную документацию](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html), там все подробно расписано.

В частности `READ_PHONE_STATE` относится к ["опасным разрешениям"](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html#normal-dangerous), которые теперь необходимо запрашивать не при установке приложения, а в рантайме